# How to fix 'configure: error: cannot find java include files'?

Tags: prolog, jpl

To install jpl(A Java Interface to Prolog),when I type 'make', it shows

```
 checking symlink for /etc/alternatives/javac... /usr/bin/gcj-wrapper-4.4
 configure: error: cannot find java include files
 make: *** [installed] Error 1
```

How to fix it?

Thank you~

Comment: This may be related to your Java installation in your Linux (UNIX?) distribution. You may need to install some `-dev` packages for Java too, or install the Sun ones (sun-jdk-sdk).

Comment: I have already installed gcj-jdk in ubuntu. And it is the same situation. What is the next step? Thank you~

Comment: what I say is to install sun-jdk instead of gcj, just in case there is any incompatibility.

Comment: I solve this problem by your hint. Please give this as an answer, and I will accept it. Thank you~

Comment: OK, done! Glad to be of help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the OP request, I post the answer. Try to install the sun-jdk package instead. May be some incompatibility with gcj packages.

Comment: Install sun-jdk by apt-get:sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ lucid partner";
sudo apt-get update;
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk sun-java6-plugin;
sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-6-sun;